# Man hides from boss by disguising himself as an armchair

Tags: identify-this-movie

I slightly remember a scene taken in an office (maybe in USA) in which there are two men: one who enters the office (I suppose a boss) and another one which always camouflages/disguises himself; in particular, I remember him **inside** an armchair (composed like a dress) and, even if I'm not totally sure, dressed as the wallpaper in another scene.

Can you spot the title? I suppose it's a movie from the mid/late '90s… (I was very young; at least the early 2000s).

Comment: This sounds like one of the Leslie Nielson spy-type comedies... Hmm.

Comment: First thing I thought of was Horace Slughorn.[Slughorn transform from his chair disguise back into human when Dumbledore prods him](http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20090702001058/harrypotter/images/3/3c/Horace_Slughorn%2C_disguise_himself_as_a_chair.gif)

Comment: @TrishLing: No, but it wasn't very different… (expect the daylight, etc).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Might be [Spy Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spy_Hard) (1996).

> Secret agent WD-40 Dick Steele (Leslie Nielsen) has his work cut out
>   for him. Along with the mysterious and lovely Veronique Ukrinsky,
>   Agent 3.14, he must rescue the kidnapped Barbara Dahl and stop the
>   evil genius, a General named Rancor (Andy Griffith), from seizing
>   control of the entire world.
>
> Rancor was wounded in an earlier encounter and no longer has arms.
>   However, he can "arm" himself by attaching robotic limbs with various
>   weapons attached. Steele is talked out of retirement by an old friend,
>   agent Steven Bishop (Robert Guillaume), and given his new assignment
>   by **The Director (Charles Durning), who also is testing out a variety
>   of elaborate disguises.** At headquarters, Steele encounters an old
>   agency nemesis, Norm Coleman (Barry Bostwick), and flirts with the
>   Director's adoring secretary, referred to as Miss Cheevus (Marcia Gay
>   Harden).
>
> On the job, Steele is assisted by an agent named Kabul (John Ales),
>   who gives him rides in a never-ending variety of specially designed
>   cars. They seek help from McLuckey (Mason Gamble), a blond child, home
>   alone, who is very good at fending off intruders. Steele resists the
>   temptations of a dangerous woman (Alexandra Paul) he finds waiting for
>   him in bed. But he does work very closely with Agent 3.14 (Nicollette
>   Sheridan), whose father, Professor Ukrinsky (Elya Baskin), is also
>   being held captive by Rancor.
>
> Everything comes to an explosive conclusion at the General's remote
>   fortress, where Steele rescues both Barbara Dahl (Stephanie Romanov)
>   and Miss Cheevus and launches a literally disarmed Rancor into outer
>   space, saving mankind.

Clip of the chair scene:

From [CrankyCritic.com](http://www.crankycritic.com/archive/spyhard.html):

> In some ways Spy Hard is a twisted inside out and played on its side
>   version of Buck Henry and Mel Brooks' Get Smart television series.
>   This time though, Agents 86 and 99 are nowhere to be seen. Agent 22 is
>   now the **Director (played by Charles Durning) and he has moved up in
>   the world, impersonating furniture, rugs, Venetian blinds and other
>   large household items**. Borrow the undersexed secretary and secret
>   weapons designer from the James Bond movies, stir it all up and see
>   how many jokes about flatulence you can come up with.

Comment: Yeah, setting & year of release make more sense than mine.

Comment: Yes, it was that! Thank you so much!
(even if I remember it slightly different, but… I was very, very young)

Comment: Called it. Boo yah!